# How to merge a branch with a single project into master with multiple projects in separate folders?

Tags: git

I want to have a single repo to store related React Native projects, having one separate folder for each one of them. I have the following setup:

- master

```
root
 |
 +-- project-a
 |  |  
 |  +-- App.js
 |  +-- package.json
 |  +-- ...
```

- project-b branch

```
root
 |
 +-- App.js
 +-- package.json
 +-- ...
```

I want to end up with the following:

- master

```
root
 |
 +-- project-a
 |  |  
 |  +-- App.js
 |  +-- package.json
 |  +-- ...
 +-- project-b
 |  |  
 |  +-- App.js
 |  +-- package.json
 |  +-- ...
```

When I run `git merge project-b` on master the folder-project-a disappears and its files are moved and edited if they have the same name in project-b.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are project-a and project-b very similar or identical? It's possible Git is considering this merge a rename (i.e. all the files where moved from `project-a` to the root directory).

Comment: They are identical and that is exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything in root of project-b branch should go to direcotry `project-b`:

1. Checkout project-b branch, create a directory `project-b` there and move everything to the new directory. Commit the moved files in project-b branch.
2. Checkout master branch and merge project-b.

Comment: I did this but didn't work. As project-a and project-b have same file names, git assumed it was a rename, i.e project-a/App.js was renamed to project-b/App.js.

I ended up only with project-b folder in master's root.